# Why does charAt not detect a string?

Tags: javascript

Why does the following function return a vowel at index 2 when, index 2 is NOT a vowel?

```
 function isVowel(name) {
   console.log("The third letter of " + name + " " + "is " + name.charAt(2))
   if (name.charAt(2) === "a" || "i" || "o" || "u")
   console.log("3rd letter is vowel")
   else
   console.log("3rd letter is NOT vowel")
}

isVowel("abcdefg")

/*Outputs:*/ The third letter of abcdefg is c
3rd letter is vowel
```

Comment: `name.charAt(2) === "a" || "i" || "o" || "u"` that condition doesn't work. You are checking if `charAt(2)` is `"a"` then checking `if ("i")` which passes, so anything that is _not_ `"a"` is also considered a vowel.

Comment: Hey "e" and "y" are also a vowels !

Comment: I see. Thank you kindly.

Comment: So five people post equally helpful answers in less than 30 seconds and I'm supposed to pick a winner based upon what criteria? Seems unfair. Thanks All!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript (and all the other languages with similar syntax), this line:

```
if (name.charAt(2) === "a" || "i" || "o" || "u")
```

means

- if name.charAt(2) === "a"
- or "i"
- or "o"
- or "u"

it does not mean

- if name.charAt(2) === "a"
- or name.charAt(2) === "i"
- or name.charAt(2) === "o"
- or name.charAt(2) === "u"

In a lot of languages you'd get an error because `"i"` isn't a boolean value, so `|| "i"` is an odd thing to say; but JavaScript is happy to do type coercion, and so `false || "e"` results in `true` because `"e"` is a "truthy"<sup>1</sup> value.

To make it mean what you want it to mean, you have to repeat the left-hand operand:

```
if (name.charAt(2) === "a" ||
    name.charAt(2) === "i" ||
    name.charAt(2) === "o" ||
    name.charAt(2) === "u")
```

You might want to use a variable to avoid repeatedly calling `charAt`, or look at doing something else, like this typical "is X in Y" approach:

```
if ("aiou".indexOf(name.charAt(2) !== -1)
```

---

Side note: Aren't you missing "e" (and sometimes "y")? ;-)

---

<sup>1</sup> "truthy value" - Values that coerce to `true` when used as booleans are *truthy*; ones that coerce to `false` are "falsy." The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`; all other values are truthy.

Answer (score 2):

A [non-empty string is treated as a truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) in JS so the if statement would be always `true`. If the first condition `name.charAt(2) === "a"` fails it will check the second condition `"i"` which would be always treated as truthy since it's non-empty string.

Instead, you can do something simple  like this using [`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

```
if ("aiou".indexOf(name.charAt(2)) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the if condition to
name.charAt(2)==='a' || name.charAt(2)==='i' || name.charAt(2)==='o'||name.charAt(2)==='u'

Comment: Sure, but **why**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check every letter with a single comparison.

```js
function isVowel(name) {
    console.log("The third letter of " + name + " " + "is " + name.charAt(2))
    if (name.charAt(2) === "a" || name.charAt(2) === "i" || name.charAt(2) === "o" || name.charAt(2) === "u") {
        console.log("3rd letter is vowel");
    } else {
        console.log("3rd letter is NOT vowel");
    }
}

isVowel("abcdefg");
```

A shorter ocde could be to check a string with the vowels and get the position of the letter, to check against.

```js
function isVowel(name) {
    console.log("The third letter of " + name + " " + "is " + name.charAt(2))
    if ('aeiou'.indexOf(name[2]) !== -1) {
        console.log("3rd letter is vowel");
    } else {
        console.log("3rd letter is NOT vowel");
    }
}

isVowel("abcdefg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `Object` as a `hash map` to check in constant time if a character is a vowel (your vowel check condition was wrong, it is always returning `true`)

```
var vowels = {
  a: true,
  i: true,
  e: true,
  o: true,
  u: true
}

if(name.charAt(2) in vowels) {
 ...
}
```

Why is your condition always returning `true`?
Because those are all equivalent in your case:

```
if (name.charAt(2) === "a" || "i" || "o" || "u")
if ((name.charAt(2) === "a") || ("i" || "o" || "u"))
if ((name.charAt(2) === "a") || true)
if (THIS_CAN_BE_ANYTHING || true)
if (true) // So, your condition is always true
```

Answer (score 1):

The `||` operator does not work like that:

```
if (name.charAt(2) === "a" || "i" || "o" || "u")
```

is syntactically correct but it won't do what you expect. You need to do a separate comparison to each vowel. Alternatively, you can keep the vowels in a string and check by search or lookup:

```
if ("aeiou".indexOf(name.charAt(2)) >= 0)
```

or

```
if ("aeiou".includes(name.charAt(2)))
```

(The `.includes()` function used in the latter example doesn't have widespread support yet.)